# SSRS Dataset embedded SQL script - issue using tmpdb

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

IN SSRS 2008 I have a data set called "`CompletionRate`", and I'm using serveral global tmp table. There are two scripts used and on the final script I call both global temp table using inner join, but when I execute the report the first time I get an invalid column error. When I ran the sql script by section it works fine.

> "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'CompletionRate'.
>   (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Invalid column name 'CallMonthName'. Invalid
>   column name 'CallMonthName'. Invalid column name 'CallMonth'. Invalid
>   column name 'CallMonthName'. Invalid column name 'CallYear'. Invalid
>   column name 'CallMonth'. Invalid column name 'CallMonthName'. Invalid
>   column name 'CallYear'. "

What am i doing wrong? Any workaround?

Comment: Impossible to tell if you don't show us the SQL code. Does the statement work in the Management Studio?

Comment: I was going to show it but it is not allowing me to include the code it is erroring out.

Comment: it is only allowing 152 characters.

Comment: Don't add the code as comment - edit your question!

Comment: I need 10 badge to post a pic . thanks anyways, i will find another resource.

Comment: As I said, put the code into your question.

Comment: I did, inside {} which is code, but once i submit it it is erroring out.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is hard to tell what the issue is. It may be that, due to the **JOIN**, you have fields with the same name. 
Do the field names show up in the **Fields** tab of your **Dataset Properties**?
Can you go to the query **Designer** in the **Dataset Properties** and run your query?

Comment: No. You just need to copy it to the question body's text field and then indent it by 4 spaces. You can also select the text and then press the {} button.